# Trouble with vector.insert()

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm trying to insert an element in a vector but it seems I'm doing something wrong.

Here's where I declare the vector:

`std::vector<Dice> dicearray;`

This is the line that throws the errors:

`dicearray.insert(dicearray.size()-1 ,Dice());`

And these are the error that are thrown:

`Error (active)     no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert [with _Ty=Dice, _Alloc=std::allocator<Dice>]" matches the argument list    ConsoleApplication3 c:\Users\Miguel\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp   60`

and

`Error  C2664   'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Dice>>> std::vector<Dice,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Dice>>>,unsigned int,const _Ty &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Dice>>>' ConsoleApplication3 c:\users\miguel\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp   60`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: why don't you use `push_back`?

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  This was valid pre C++11

Comment: I wanted to add elements in several positions, not just the last. But that would also have worked for this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide an *iterator* to the position you want to insert it to (see reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/). The error is basically saying there's no function which takes these types of arguments (number, element). So:

```
dicearray.insert(dicearray.end(), Dice()); // Insert element at the end (yes, without - 1)
```

Note that, if there's an element at the desired position already, all elements from that location to the end are shifted one position "up".

If you just want to *add* the element, you can use `push_back` (and then you don't specify the position, it's inserted in the last position):

```
dicearray.push_back(Dice());
```

Comment: Got it, it works now. Thanks, didn't notice that it needed an iterator, not a number. Thanks.